# Android: Toolbar with text view not quite centering

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am having a problem with centering a text view within a toolbar.

When the text gets too long it looks like this

[image]

As you can see the text is slightly too much to the right or the left navigation icon has some padding.

The image below has layout bounds on

[image]

When the text is small it is fine

[image]

Likewise if the optional logo is visible (The spanner is just a placeholder) then the text seen in the first image displays fine

[image]

Here is the code. Please leave a comment if you need to see anything else

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ersen.toolbarcentreproblem.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Set Holiday Set Holiday Set Holiday Set Holiday"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }
}
```

**What I have tried**

- contentInsetLeft
- contentInsetRight
- contentInsetEnd
- contentInsertStart

All set to 0dp on toolbar had no effect

I also tried applying padding on the text view but this caused issues when the text is small.

**Edit 1: TextView width set to match_parent**

Same problem

[image]

**Edit 2: Trying Narendra Sorathiya solution**

[image]

Comment: Just set your `logo` `ImageView`'s `visibility` to `invisible` instead of `gone`.

Comment: @MikeM. Hi thanks for the reply. This can work in some cases but in others I might have a inflated menu and not sure if I want to code around that.

Comment: change your `SET HOLIDAY` `TextView` width  to `match_parent`.

Comment: @Ironman Hi thanks for the reply. I tried match_parent and I get the same issue. I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: What is strange, if you pretend that the navigation icon is not there, the text is actually centered so for some reason it is not taking into account the navigation icon

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:visibility="visible"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Events"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I took some parts of the code and it has appeared to reduce the spacing between the right navigation icon and the text.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I pasted the code into my project, the text is still not center, please see my edit 2 which has a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring what @Mike M said about making

> Just set your logo ImageView's visibility to invisible instead of gone

In my Toolbar I have this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:text="Set Holiday Holiday Set Set S"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Notice the space widget

In `onResume`, `MainActivity` I have this logic

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mLogo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE || mToolbar.getMenu().size() > 0) {
            mSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        mSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

If the Logo is visible or the toolbar has menu items, it will hide the space view otherwise it sets it to visible.

This has solved my issues, the text now appears center in all cases.

There is one issue with this

```
mToolbar.getMenu().size() > 0
```

Since this code is `onResume` of an activity, it would be called before the fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu so it could end up false when it is in fact true, I am going to be exploring this more